# How to display array data from json field to the blade view?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a json field `produce_stored` to store array data.

Warehouse Table Structure

[image]

In the Warehouse Model I'm using $casts to store the array data

```
protected $casts = [
    'produce_stored' => 'array'
];
```

In the WarehouseController - index method

```
$warehouses = DB::table('warehouses')
                ->join('regions', 'regions.id', '=', 'warehouses.region_id')
                ->join('districts', 'districts.id', '=', 'warehouses.district_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'warehouses.agent_assigned')
                ->select(
                    'warehouses.id',
                    'warehouses.name as warehouseName',
                    'warehouses.ownership_type',
                    'warehouses.capacity',
                    'warehouses.produce_stored',  // json field with array data
                    'regions.name as regionName', 
                    'districts.name as districtName',
                    'users.name as agent_assigned',
                    'warehouses.status'
                    )
                ->get();

return view('admin.warehouses.index', compact('warehouses'));
```

In the blade view

```
{{ $warehouse->produce_stored }}
```

This is the output in the browser

```
["1", "2"]
```

When I try looping through the array to get the produce ids to load the produce names

```
@foreach ($warehouse->produceStored as $produce)
    {{$produce}}
@endforeach
```

The above throws an error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How do I get the produce ids from the produce_stored field?

Comment: Problem is, that you are not using model, but DB call. In his case, the casting is not called. Replace `DB::table('warehouses')` with model calling, `\App\Warehouse::select ...` (correct Model placing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two choices:

```
 <?php $warehouse->produceStored = json_decode($warehouse->produceStored, false); ?>
```

and then try

```
@foreach ($warehouse->produceStored as $produce)
    {{$produce}}
@endforeach
```

2- like Autista_z said in comment:

```
$warehouses = Warehouse::query()
                ->join('regions', 'regions.id', '=', 'warehouses.region_id')
                ->join('districts', 'districts.id', '=', 'warehouses.district_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'warehouses.agent_assigned')
                ->select(
                    'warehouses.id',
                    'warehouses.name as warehouseName',
                    'warehouses.ownership_type',
                    'warehouses.capacity',
                    'warehouses.produce_stored',  // json field with array data
                    'regions.name as regionName', 
                    'districts.name as districtName',
                    'users.name as agent_assigned',
                    'warehouses.status'
                    )
                ->get();
```

note: replace Warehouse with your model name if they are not the same...

Comment: Now that the produce ids are listed. How do I retrieve the produce names?

Comment: i think you should load them in controller before send them to view